# Is it okay to restart breastfeeding after a delay, and continue until after a child is 2 years old?

Tags: toddler, breastfeeding

Around six months ago, we stopped breastfeeding my first child  after my wife and I found out that my wife was 3 months pregnant.

In about 1 month my wife will give birth to our second child. At that time, my first child will be 20 months old.

We are planning to start to give breast milk to him again, because we still have 4 months to go until he is 24 months old. Is that ok? And also is it ok if we plan to breastfeed him for longer than 4 months? It means my first child will still be breastfed after he is older than 24 months old.

Comment: Just as a warning, you might run into conflicts with the 2yo and the newborn sharing the breast.  You'll have to teach the 2yo to share with his younger sibling.  And it might become another point of jealous contention - "you take all of my parents' time AND you nurse my milk all the time".

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with any of what you're doing.  There are many women who breastfeed their children until after their 2nd birthday.

My big question is how amenable your 20-month-old is going to be to returning to the breast and breastmilk after taking a 9-month hiatus.  If he's been drinking another animal or plant-based milk since his initial weaning, he might not be interested in returning.  Likewise, a 2-year-old is incredibly active and might not want to so sit (or lie or whatever) the length of time that would be required for breastfeeding.  If he's been drinking from sippy cups, he might prefer the freedom of mobility that comes with being able to take his drink with him wherever he goes.

On the other hand, if he has expressed interest in returning to breastfeeding, then doing so isn't going to harm him.  After all, breast milk is a substance that is designed to be ingested by other humans.